# Displaying results of a function in two different types of elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using this function to total the sum of all values in a column. I would like to have the results display in an input box as well as to the cell that it currently does. I'm just a little stuck on the syntax for mixing the two since one needs to reference a value.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#front_finish, #back_finish').change(function(){
    function tally (selector) {
        $(selector).each(function () {
            var total = 0,
                column = $(this).siblings(selector).andSelf().index(this);
            $(this).parents().prevUntil(':has(' + selector + ')').each(function () {
                total += parseFloat($('td.sum:eq(' + column + ')', this).html()) || 0;
            })
            $(this).html(total);
        });
    }
    tally('td.total');
    });
});
```

Input

```
<input type="text" name="glass_total" id="glass_total" value="0" />
```

Table

```
<table id="data">
<tr>
    <th>Finish</th>
    <th>Pattern</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Front Finish:</td>
    <td><span id="front_finish_name">Mirror</span></td>
    <td class="sum" id="front_finish_price">15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Front Pattern:</td>
    <td><span id="front_pattern_name"></span></td>
    <td class="sum" id="front_pattern_price"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Back Finish:</td>
    <td><span id="back_finish_name">Mirror</span></td>
    <td class="sum" id="back_finish_price">15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Back Pattern:</td>
    <td><span id="back_pattern_name"></span></td>
    <td class="sum" id="back_pattern_price"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2" align="right">Total</th>
    <td class="total"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more html?  I am not sure of the relationship between the textbox and the column.

Comment: Yes. I've updated the post. There isn't really a relationship between the two. I'm trying to email the results of the total via PHP and it would be much easier to send the value of an input rather than some text in a cell.

Comment: So how does glass_total interact with the columns?

Comment: It doesn't. I figured this would be as easy as putting the id of the input where the function displays results, `tally('td.total');`, and I only wasn't sure how to incorporate `.val()` but, I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your jquery may be a little off.  Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#front_finish, #back_finish').change(function () {
        var total = 0, temp;
        $("#data td.sum").each(function () {
            temp = $(this).html();
            if (!temp) {
                return;
            }
            temp = parseFloat(temp);
            if (isNaN(temp)) {
                return;
            }
            total += temp;
        });
        $("#data td.total").html(total);
        $("#glass_total").val(total); // if you want it in the textbox
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by the each as the html you posted only has one `td.total`.  If there really is just one then all you have to do is this:

```
$("#glass_total").val(total);
```

If there are multiple you'll need to explain a bit more since the input appears to be unique.

Comment: It is unique. I would just like the total to appear in both td.total and as the value of #glass_total. Please excuse me if I'm being blunt or obtuse.

Comment: Then I think this will do it for you.